# using a string value as boolean in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it Possible to use a value as a type string in where clause. something like this:

```
 select * from 
 (
 select datepart(dw,b.Date) as Tag,b.[Customer No_],b.Date,b.[POS Holiday],b.Nonworking,
 case
  when datepart(dw,b.Date)=1 then (select '[Valid at Monday]=1')
  when datepart(dw,b.Date)=2 then (select '[Valid at Tuesday]=1')
  when datepart(dw,b.Date)=3 then (select '[Valid at Wednesday]=1')
  when datepart(dw,b.Date)=4 then (select '[Valid at Thursday]=1')
  when datepart(dw,b.Date)=5 then (select '[Valid at Friday]=1')
  when datepart(dw,b.Date)=6 then (select '[Valid at Saturday]=1')
  when datepart(dw,b.Date)=7 then (select '[Valid at Sunday]=1')
 end as  TestB 
 from [CustomerBPCal] b
 ) as a 
 left join [CustomerShopAndArrivalTime] as c on c.[Customer No_]=a.[Customer No_]  where a.TestB
```

if yes, how can I change my code to run such a query?

Comment: do you want to add `where a.testb = 'somevalue'`? If so, feel free to add and check.

Comment: for example I want to use ´where '[Valid at Monday]=1´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criteria belongs in the `WHERE` clause. It seems you simply want to do this:

```
WHERE (datepart(dw, b.Date) = 1 And [Valid at Monday] = 1)
   OR (datepart(dw, b.Date) = 2 And [Valid at Tuesday] = 1)
   OR ...
```

or, in case the `[Valid at ...]` columns belong to the outher joined table `CustomerShopAndArrivalTime`, then in the `ON` clause of course:

```
ON c.[Customer No_] = a.[Customer No_]  
AND
(   (datepart(dw, b.Date) = 1 And c.[Valid at Monday] = 1)
 OR (datepart(dw, b.Date) = 2 And c.[Valid at Tuesday] = 1)
 OR ...
)
```